# How to send SIGTERM to a process by process name in QNX cpp code?

Tags: c++, qnx

E.g: I have a process called foo.

Typically in console, I can type `slay foo` then foo terminates.
Also, in a cpp code I can issue a system call with `system("slay foo");`

I know the system() is a heavy fork call that should be avoid. Is there any other function in `<csignal>` or `<cstdlib>` I can choose?

I've read SignalKill() and SignalKill_r(), both need pid which I cannot provide.

Comment: busybox source code shows you how to do this, or you might simply link with libbb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not as simple as one might think. Linux doesn't provide a `syscall` that gives you the `PID` of a process by its name.

Assuming `QNX`s filesystem is similar to standard UNI, you might want to read [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160326151210/http://phoxis.org/2013/09/13/find-process-ids-of-a-running-process-by-name/) to understand how to find a process's `PID` using its name, and then use that `PID` with `SignalKill` or `SignalKill_r`

Here's the code to find a process's `PID` using its name in C. I can't test it on `QNX`, but it works on `Ubuntu`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <libgen.h>

/* checks if the string is purely an integer
 * we can do it with `strtol' also
 */
int check_if_number (char *str)
{
  int i;
  for (i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (!isdigit (str[i]))
    {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

#define MAX_BUF 1024
#define PID_LIST_BLOCK 32

int *pidof (char *pname)
{
  DIR *dirp;
  FILE *fp;
  struct dirent *entry;
  int *pidlist, pidlist_index = 0, pidlist_realloc_count = 1;
  char path[MAX_BUF], read_buf[MAX_BUF];

  dirp = opendir ("/proc/");
  if (dirp == NULL)
  {
    perror ("Fail");
    return NULL;
  }

  pidlist = malloc (sizeof (int) * PID_LIST_BLOCK);
  if (pidlist == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  while ((entry = readdir (dirp)) != NULL)
  {
    if (check_if_number (entry->d_name))
    {
      strcpy (path, "/proc/");
      strcat (path, entry->d_name);
      strcat (path, "/comm");

      /* A file may not exist, it may have been removed.
       * dut to termination of the process. Actually we need to
       * make sure the error is actually file does not exist to
       * be accurate.
       */
      fp = fopen (path, "r");
      if (fp != NULL)
      {
        fscanf (fp, "%s", read_buf);
        if (strcmp (read_buf, pname) == 0)
        {
          /* add to list and expand list if needed */
          pidlist[pidlist_index++] = atoi (entry->d_name);
          if (pidlist_index == PID_LIST_BLOCK * pidlist_realloc_count)
          {
            pidlist_realloc_count++;
            pidlist = realloc (pidlist, sizeof (int) * PID_LIST_BLOCK * pidlist_realloc_count); //Error check todo
            if (pidlist == NULL)
            {
              return NULL;
            }
          }
        }
        fclose (fp);
      }
    }
  }


  closedir (dirp);
  pidlist[pidlist_index] = -1; /* indicates end of list */
  return pidlist;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int *list, i;

  if (argc != 2)
  {
    printf ("Usage: %s proc_name\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
  }
  list = pidof (argv[1]);
  for (i=0; list[i] != -1; i++)
  {
    printf ("%d ", list[i]);
  }
  free (list);
  if (list[0] != -1)
  {
    printf ("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it takes this much work (opening directories and files etc.) then you may as well just use *system("slay foo")*

Comment: @ooga Who says `slay` is more efficient? I'm not aware of any `qnx` API to make it faster

Comment: Thanks, it works good!  I'm wondering why QNX doesn't provide a system call to return such thing.

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert a process name to a pid, you need to dig through QNX's /proc filesystem.  I wrote a book called "The QNX Cookbook" which is now available for free online at QNX's website (http://www.qnx.com/download/feature.html?programid=26184).  Go to page 222, "Iterating through the list of processes" and copy the code that iterates through the list of processes.  This will allow you to search through all processes for whichever ones you want to kill (it will give you the PID you need).

```
void
iterate_processes (void)
{
  struct dirent   *dirent;
  DIR             *dir;
  int             r;
  int             pid;

  // 1) find all processes
  if (!(dir = opendir ("/proc"))) {
    fprintf (stderr, "%s:  couldn't open /proc, errno %d\n",
             progname, errno);
    perror (NULL);
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while (dirent = readdir (dir)) {
    // 2) we are only interested in process IDs
    if (isdigit (*dirent -> d_name)) {
      pid = atoi (dirent -> d_name);
      iterate_process (pid);
    }
  }
  closedir (dir);
}

void
iterate_process (int pid)
{
  char      paths [PATH_MAX];
  int       fd;

  // 1) set up structure
  static struct {
    procfs_debuginfo    info;
    char                buff [PATH_MAX];
  } name;

  sprintf (paths, "/proc/%d/as", pid);

  if ((fd = open (paths, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
    return;
  }

  // 2) ask for the name
  if (devctl (fd, DCMD_PROC_MAPDEBUG_BASE, &name,
              sizeof (name), 0) != EOK) {
    if (pid == 1) {
      strcpy (name.info.path, "(procnto)");
    } else {
      strcpy (name.info.path, "(n/a)");
    }
  }

  // 3) we can compare against name.info.path here...
  do_process (pid, fd, name.info.path);
  close (fd);
}
```

By supplying whatever actions you want for "do_process()", you can e.g. kill by name, etc.